# Are we in Yemos Hamoshiach?

Tags: ymoth-hamoshiach

I have seen medroshim quoted saying that there is a stage of Geula during the times of Galus.

Are we currently in that stage?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Where have you seen these Midrashim? Could you cite them? What makes you think that we may or may not be in this pseudo-redemption stage? I’m not trying to be tough - this seems like an excellent question; I’m simply trying to understand it. Hope to see you around!

Comment: The medrash is found in medrash Raba shir hashirim parsha 2 passuk 33

Comment: Maybe you could [edit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/88285/edit) that information into your question?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Probably. But it's not like any ancient sources cited our time and said that it was the yemos haMoshiach. On a side note, many contemporary gedolim have said time and time again that we should be gearing up for geulah sheleimah.

Comment: rambam says we can only know retroactively after it all happens

Comment: **I have seen medroshim** Which Midrashim?

Comment: Check out the following book and video that deal with the issue [Need to Know: Crucial Knowledge for the End-of-Days](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1549879189) and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_J7dG1FImno

Answer (score 2):

The gemara in [Avodoh Zarah Daf 9a](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.9a.5) mentions that for the past 1778 years we are already in Yemos Hamoshiach. Year 4000 of creation was 172 years after the churban Beis Hamikdash.

> תנא דבי אליהו ששת אלפים שנה הוי העולם שני אלפים תוהו שני אלפים תורה שני אלפים ימות המשיח בעונותינו שרבו יצאו מהן מה שיצאו מהן
>   In relation to the discussion on the calculation of years, the Gemara states that one of the Sages of the school of Eliyahu taught: The world is destined to exist for six thousand years. For two thousand years the world was waste, as the Torah had not yet been given. The next set of two thousand years are the time period of the Torah. The last set of two thousand years are the period designated for the days of the Messiah, but due to our many sins there are those years that have been taken from them, i.e., such and such years have already passed and have been taken from the two thousand years that are designated for the Messiah, and the Messiah has not yet arrived. Whenever a tanna taught this baraita, he would insert the number of years that was correct for his time.

Answer (score 1):

the Rebbe said on the 20th of kislev 5752 we are in Yemos Hamoshia

https://dvarmalchus.files.wordpress.com/2014/12/19-20kislev5752_yemoshamoshiach.png

[image]

for the audio recoding see minute 10:05 [here](http://www.chabad.org/555112/)

Comment: Notably, everyone else disagrees with this.

Comment: @DoubleAA "Everyone" is a pretty broad term, though I will agree with you and say the vast majority of Jewish authorities disagree with the Lubavitcher Rebbe on this.

Comment: @DoubleAA , the premise is mistaken. From the audio before this point, it's clear that it refers to the generation of moshiach, and not that moshiach is here already. If that wasn't clear from here, there are countless times when the Rebbe talks about bringing moshiach, saying "how long do we have to wait", and צדיק גזר והקדוש ברוך הוא מקיים (that whenever tzadikim declare something as a fact, such as "moshiach is coming by this date" or "now!" that functions as a special type of tefila). Also, he says this whole piece is from "the Nasi of our generation, my father in law, the Rebbe".

Answer (score 0):

The Lubavitcher Rebbe in Hayom Yom actually says that we are.

[**Shevat 8**](https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/6058/jewish/Hayom-Yom-Shevat-8.htm):

> In these days especially, when by G‑d's kindness we stand at the
> threshold of redemption, we must make every conceivable effort to
> strengthen every facet of our religion. Mitzvot must be observed
> b'hidur, with "beauty," beyond minimal requirements. Customs must be
> kept scrupulously, nothing compromised. It is a Mitzva and duty of
> every Rabbi in Israel to inform his congregation that the current
> tribulations and agonies are the "birth-pangs of Mashiach." G‑d is
> demanding that we return to Torah and mitzvot, that we not hinder the
> imminent coming of our righteous Mashiach.

In the entry of **Sivan 18** the Rebbe writes:

> **This is the actual time of the "footsteps of Mashiach."** It is therefore imperative for every Jew to seek his fellow's welfare - whether old or young - to inspire the other to teshuva (return), so that he will not fall out - G‑d forbid - of the community of Israel who will shortly be privileged, with G‑d's help, to experience complete redemption. (emphasis mine)

The Gemara (Sanhedrin 97a) says that during the generation in which Moshiach comes, troubles increase. Rashi understands this as:

> עד שלא כלתה צרה ראשונה שניה ממהרת לבא פקודה כמו לא נפקד - When the first trouble is over, the second trouble already arrived (my own translation)

Do we see this in our generation? The last 100 years?